# Update Data into MySQL Table If Already Exists

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the following script to Insert data and upload image to server

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST') {

    $image = $_POST['image'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $rId = $_POST['rId'];

    $path = "uploads/$rId.png";

    $sql = "insert into room_info (r_id,url,name) VALUES ('$rId','$path','$name')";

    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
        file_put_contents($path, base64_decode($image));
        echo "Successfully Uploaded";
    }

    mysqli_close($con);

    } else {

    echo "Error";
}
```

Now, I want to modify above script, which can allow me, to update data into mysql table and most importantly update image into uploads folder if rId already exists

I know that below query I can use to read data from mysql, to check whether record already exists or not for particular rId

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM room_info WHERE r_id = '$rId' ";
```

And to update I could use something like this:

```
update room_info set name = $name where r_id = $rId;
```

But curious to know that How can I use all these query together, to insert record, to check record, to update record and at last but not least to update image into uploads folder

**NOTE:** THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE QUESTION; BECAUSE I JUST NOT NEED TO UPDATE THE DATA IN MYSQL TABLE, EVEN IMAGE IN UPLOADS FOLDER

Comment: check that row with corresponding id is already exists or not with  num_rows() 
function and if data already exists than update it else insert it (because it's a new record)

Comment: @Bhavin Can  you show me the modified script, which you think I should check... Actually I am not PHP Developer, just a new learner and trying to learn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Make 'r_id' column unique in room_info and 
Change your query

```
$sql = "insert into room_info (r_id,url,name) VALUES ('$rId','$path','$name')";

to 

$sql = "insert into room_info (r_id,url,name) VALUES ('$rId','$path','$name')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE url='$path'";
```

Comment: so how can i update image in uploads folder

Comment: @Oreo the same way you are already doing it in your existing code.

Comment: you are just awesome, and your solution is too AWESOME :) too much easy